# How to maintain a build directory of CMake project in a git repository?

Tags: github, cmake

I am working on a project with a friend and using GitHub to work simultaneously. I am new to git and when one of us push the changes to GitHub, it changes the build folder and changes settings in the CMake files.
How can we work with git without affecting each other's build files?

Comment: how are you configuring the build folder? Are you tracking the build folder in git?

Answer (score 4):

The CMake build directory should contain files and directories *generated* via CMake, and should not need to be kept in source control.

I have worked with a few CMake-based projects on Github. It has never been a standard practice (in my experience) to check the build folder into your git repository (or any source control).

One huge advantage of a CMake project over non-CMake projects is that the build artifacts (such as Visual Studio project files, and IDE files with user-specific settings) do *not* need to be checked into your repository; CMake generates these for you!

A simple CMake-based project structure would appear like this. You should check in your CMakeLists.txt files and source code into the git (or other) source control. But, I **highly** encourage you structure your project such that nothing in your CMake binary directory needs to be tracked by source control:

```
projectRoot
├───.git/                  
├───build/                  <---- Do NOT check in anything from 'build'.
│   CMakeLists.txt          <---- Check in your top-level CMake source file.
├───src/                    <---- Check in all your code and other CMake files.
│       CMakeLists.txt
│       MyClass.cpp
│       main.cpp
```

This way, each person working with the repository has their *own* CMake build directory. If changes to the build need to be made, these changes should be reflected in the CMakeLists.txt files. Then, when changes to the CMakeLists.txt files are pulled down to your local repository, CMake can re-generate any project/buildsystem files that need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.gitignore` file (at the root directory) with the list of directories/files you don't want to version i.e. your build dir...